# Tiling an image taking long

Tags: python, image-processing

I have the following code that basically takes an image and puts it on pixels, in other words takes each pixel of the image and creates a 10x10 "pixel" which includes the whitespace between them, as shown below:

[image]

This becomes amazingly slow and I was wondering if that is just normal or am I doing some redundant operation?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import lena 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def rect(x, y):

    res = (np.abs(x) < .5)*(np.abs(y) < .5)
    return res

def placeOnSLM(FF, image):

    step = .1
    x, y = np.mgrid[0:image.shape[0]+step:step, 0:image.shape[1]+step:step]
    outImage = np.zeros(x.shape)+np.min(image)
    for ix in range(image.shape[0]):
        print ix,'of',image.shape[0]
        for iy in range(image.shape[1]):
            outImage[(np.abs(x-ix-.5)/FF < .5) * (np.abs(y-iy-.5)/FF < .5)] = image[ix, iy]
#             outImage += image[ix, iy]*rect((x-ix-.5)/FF, (y-iy-.5)/FF)
    return outImage

if __name__ == '__main__':

    num = 10
    image = placeOnSLM(.9, lena()[:num,:num])
    plt.imshow(lena()[:num,:num],'gray', interpolation='none')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(image,'gray',interpolation='none')
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

EDIT:

The OS I'm using is Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: What do you mean by "becomes amazingly slow"?  Like it gets slower as you add more blocks?

Comment: yes, for n = 10 it's less than 1s then with n = 100 it's close to 10min rather than 100s, intuitively I assume it scales O(n^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big processing step is here:

```
for ix in range(image.shape[0]):
    print ix,'of',image.shape[0]
    for iy in range(image.shape[1]):
        outImage[(np.abs(x-ix-.5)/FF < .5) * (np.abs(y-iy-.5)/FF < .5)] = image[ix, iy]
```

Your runtime is `O(n^2)`, as you correctly mention in your comments.  A 1s runtime for `n = 10` should *scale* to 100s. However, you don't take into account the memory hit caused by the stored image.  Every time you go through that inner `for` loop, you add a chunk of pixels to your image.  For small values of `n`, this isn't a huge issue, but for larger values of `n` this adds up to a lot of space (proportional to `n*n` to be exact!). You don't mention your OS but it might be worthwhile to check on the memory usage of Python at these larger values of `n`.  You may see a threshold at which operations start to take a *lot* longer (i.e. don't scale well to the runtime of your code).

Good luck!

**EDIT:** Curiosity got the best of me and I wanted to see how it'd work on my machine.  I did a quick (although with large `n`, not-so-quick) runtime analysis.

Red = actual, blue = using ideal n^2 runtime

**Runtime (s) vs. n**, log scale

[image: graph with log scale]

**Runtime (s) vs. n**

[image: graph]

As you can pretty clearly see, *something* happens at around n=60.  My memory usage hit ~80-90% right around there and stayed in the 90% range for the rest of the runs.  My best guess is that it's due to the image itself in memory, because the CPU usage was also really high during those runs.

**EDIT 2**:

Turns out the large bottleneck is created by this line

```
outImage[(np.abs(x-ix-.5)/FF < .5) * (np.abs(y-iy-.5)/FF < .5)] = image[ix, iy]
```

Replacing it with the following code speeds things up significantly:

```
ixD = int(np.ceil((-FF/2 + ix + .5)*10))
ixU = int(np.ceil((FF/2 + ix + .5)*10))
iyD = int(np.ceil((-FF/2 + iy + .5)*10))
iyU = int(np.ceil((FF/2 + iy + .5)*10))
outImage[ixD:ixU, iyD:iyU] = image[ix, iy]
```

Comment: But I tried to initialise `outImage` exactly for the reason you metnion. `outImage = np.zeros(x.shape)+np.min(image)` Does simply accessing a memory space create such an issue?

Comment: @evan54 I didn't think so, but the runtime analysis had some interesting results.

Comment: duuude!! the plots are awesome! I tried it on mine and it doesn't do much to my memory usage... ie my CPU is just maxing out but memory seems fine.. I've been trying to figure out a sparse approach that may improve things, if it's a memory issue

Comment: HA I found what is going on! It's nothing to do with sparse matrices it has to do with how I address `outImage` using the True False method (not sure what the real name is). I'll edit your answer and maybe you could run the plots again?

Answer (score 2):

What about a solution which doesn't use a for loop? Not sure about it because I haven't used matplotlib much, but I assume it is similar to matlab so I will write in matlab and hopefully it is trivial to convert it to matplotlib.

The solution is simply: use matlabs imresize function to resize the image, but set interpolation to be "nearest" instead of bilinear/bicubic. If you make the image 10 times larger, it will basically make 10x10 patches with the value equal to the one pixel of the original image. The following code does it and then adds margins. (The for loop is just to test various values of n).

```
ns= [10:10:100, 500, 1000];
times= zeros(size(ns));

for i= 1:length(ns)

    n= ns(i);
    s= 10; % 10x10 pixels in the result = 1x1 of the original image
    margin= 2;

    % create the image
    im= rand(n,n);

    tic
    % resize the image
    im2= imresize(im, (s+margin)*size(im), 'nearest');

    % add margins
    [x,y]= meshgrid([0:n]*(s+margin), [1:margin]);
    inds= x(:)+y(:);
    im2(inds,:)=0; im2(:, inds)=0;

    times(i)= toc;
    % imagesc(im2); pause; % visualize

end

plot(ns, times);
```

In my test, with n=1000 the image is created in 0.96s (though I do have a quadcore i5 @ 3.3 GHz. OS: Ubuntu 11.10.